# I need to get the IP, Name of the printer queue, and serial from the print management console on Windows Server 2016 and the same servers connected

Tags: windows, powershell, foreach, printing

My problem is I can get the IP, queue name, but I never get the serial.

You can add the Print Management module in PowerShell and use the following command to get the name, IP address, serial number, and port for all printers connected to the Print Management Console:

```
Import-Module PrintManagement
$printers = Get-PrintQueue
foreach ($printer in $printers) {
    $data = @{
        Name = $printer.Name
        IP = $printer.PortName
        Serial = $printer.SerialNumber
        Port = $printer.PortName
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $data
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\printers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This command first imports the Print Management module. Then, it uses the Get-PrintQueue cmdlet to get all printers connected to the Print Management Console, then loops through each printer and retrieves the name, IP address, serial number, and port, creating an object with the information. Finally, it exports the information to a CSV file named "printers.csv" in the C:\ drive.

Please note that the IP address in the command is getting from the PortName property, which is not the IP address of the printer, but the name of the port connected to the printer.

You can also add the print servers by retrieving the information from the servers that have the Print Management Console, like this:

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\serverlist.txt"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $printers = Get-PrintQueue -ComputerName $server
    foreach ($printer in $printers) {
        $data = @{
            Server = $server
            Name = $printer.Name
            IP = $printer.PortName
            Serial = $printer.SerialNumber
            Port = $printer.PortName
        }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $data
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\printers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I ran the script above.

Comment: I’m struggling to determine what your actual question is?

Comment: Where are you getting cmdlet `Get-PrintQueue` from?  I do not see this function available in the [PrintManagement Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Comment: '@Daniel', could be the OP got that from here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WinOps/0.11.0/Content/public%5CGet-PrintQueue.ps1. @djehuti, see if you can leverage this: [PowerShell – Get Printer IP address and Port, Model information](https://shellgeek.com/powershell-get-printer-ip-address-and-port-model/)

Comment: The serial number comes from the driver for the printer.  Make sure you use the vendors driver and not the generic Microsoft driver.  Serial numbers in drivers are optional,  Microsoft standards for drivers do not contain properties for serial numbers.  Vendors who created drivers with serial number have to get the serial numbers from registers in printers that are not part of the Microsoft Standards and generic drivers will not find the serial numbers.

Comment: You can get the serial number over snmp if you want to go that route.

Comment: In addition to js2010's suggestion of using snmp, some printers also have a web interface that you may be able to leverage possibly using `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: I use to the web interface to set the printers up only. Can I use Invoke-WebRequest with PowerShell to get the serial numbers? The reason I am asking is because I manage hundreds of printers and this is pretty much the only information I can automatically get from a script and it is crucial.